# Azure AD Sign-in Log Difference for Guest Access

Tags: azure-active-directory

Are there any differences between logs for sign-in to access one’s own tenant resources and resources of a tenant where the one is invited as guest?
A customer would like to know if they can check their employees activity on different tenant where their employees are invited as guest users by analyzing AAD sign-in logs on Azure Sentinel.
The following is the summary of what I would like to ask.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Activities of the user1@contoso.com that belong to Company1.com will only be logged in company1.com logs.

So, an admin from contoso.com will not be able to track them directly.

However, through Azure Sentinel, you can collect logs from multiple tenants and if someone from company1.com authorizes Sentinel then your admin can see the logs in a single portal.

Comment: Hi ManojReddy-MSFT,

Thank you very much for your answer!